# Question About Floating Point Number System

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point

I have begun reading *Numerical Analysis* by Walter Gautschi. On page $3$, the author introduces the floating point number system as follows: a floating point number is a number representible as 
$$
\begin{equation}
\pm (.b_{-1}b_{-2}...b_{-t})_2 \cdot 2^{\pm(c_{s-1}c_{s-2}...c_0.)_2} \tag {1}
\end{equation}
$$
where $s, t$ are fixed. We denote this number system by $\mathbb{R}(s, t)$.

Then, Walter says that a number $x \in \mathbb{R}(s, t)$ is normalized if $b_{-1}=1$, and that we $"$assume all numbers in $\mathbb{R}(s, t)$ are normalized $"$.

**My Question:** Consider consider the number 
$$x = +(.00100) \cdot 2^{-(111.)}$$
Is this number an element of $\mathbb{R}(5, 3)$? According to the definition, I want to say yes. But when the author says $"$we assume all numbers in $\mathbb{R}(s, t)$ are normalized,$"$ I don't know if he is implicitly redefining $\mathbb{R}(s, t)$ to be numbers of the form $(1)$ with the *additional* requirement that $b_{-1}=1$. If we try to impose this requirement on $x$, I believe $x$ would come out to 
$$x=+(.10000) \cdot 2^{-1001}$$
which shouldn't be part of $\mathbb{R}(5, 3)$

**Background**
I am a math major taking my first numerical analysis. I do not have any prior experience with computer science or numerical mathematics.

Comment: In order to maintain unique representations, you must assume $b_{-1}\ne 0$. Otherwise you must change the exponent.

Comment: I believe that the assumption is still part of the definition.